# Do bouncing bullets have multiple chances to proc Close Enough?

Tags: borderlands-2

By bouncing bullets, I mean projectiles from weapons that are (a) eligible to be affected by Close Enough and (b) ricochet not-because of Close Enough. Madhous and Stalker are examples of such weapons. By proc, I mean (successfully) trigger or activate.

Comment: No , but if Close Enough triggered on the first bounce then they will homing to the enemy.

Answer (score -1):

My testing seems to indicate no.

Comment: could you provide a little more information on how you have tested this?

Comment: Sanctuary dummy. Trick Shot Maggie.  
I presume some answer is better than none. It's too bad you don't think that way. "This answer is useful." I will continue to provide information in this way which has not otherwise been refuted as being useful.

Comment: You could provide more details as to what your testing was.